# How to deal with many subscriptions in an Angular form with less code and good practices

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, httpclient, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular form where I have many select options, these select options are managed by Subscriptions but I am looking there is too much code for every Subscription.

Can someone suggest me a good practice to reduce the amount of code?

Thanks in advance!

Here is an example: https://github.com/jreategui07/testing-subscriptions-form

Mock server runs with: mockserver -p 8080 -m mock

```
    this.colorSC = this.catalogueService.getColors().subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        console.log(response.body);
        this.colorsData = response.body;
      },
      error => 
      {
        console.warn('Error', error);
      }
    );

    this.brandSC = this.catalogueService.getSizes().subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        console.log(response.body);
        this.brandsData = response.body;
      },
      error => 
      {
        console.warn('Error', error);
      }
    );

    this.sizeSC = this.catalogueService.getFruits().subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        console.log(response.body);
        this.sizesData = response.body;
      },
      error => 
      {
        console.warn('Error', error);
      }
    );

    this.fruitSC = this.catalogueService.getColors().subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        console.log(response.body);
        this.fruitsData = response.body;
      },
      error => 
      {
        console.warn('Error', error);
      }
    );
```

Comment: you don't need to assign the subscribe function to a variable `this.fruitSC`, `this.sizeSC` etc. and console.log should be for development only... the rest is good to go to ensure that each service call is separate, small and sweet

Comment: @JonathanReátegui Please check the answer let me know if that is what you wanted

Comment: Hi @joyBlanks, thanks for your soon answer. I am having an error in the template with the ngFor: ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: @JonathanReátegui Please check updated answer on your service class

Comment: @joyBlanks! It worked well, I just add response['body'] because I was having an error. I definitely have less code now, I will continue investigating to implement this with the http code responses. Thank you for supporting me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just hook up the observables to the select's option as observable and use the async pipe to bind the data

Declare Observables for options

```
colorSC$ : Observable<any>;
brandSC$ : Observable<any>;
sizeSC$  : Observable<any>;
fruitSC$ : Observable<any>;
```

NOTE: Use an interface instead of any I am not sure the data type so for this answer I am using any. You can define your interfaces and use them here to declare these Observable variables

You can now assign these observables, You can do it in

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private catalogueService: CatalogueService) { 
  this.anyForm = this.fb.group({
    color: [''],
    brand: [''],
    size: [''],
    fruit: [''],
  });

  this.colorSC$ = catalogueService.getColors();
  this.brandSC$ = catalogueService.getSizes();
  this.sizeSC$  = catalogueService.getFruits();
  this.fruitSC$ = catalogueService.getColors();
}
```

and in your template use the async pipe to get the items eg: `colorSC$ | async` Note that there are safe checks for code and description so that the template doesn't error out `item?.code` and `item?.description`

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="anyForm">
  <label>Color:</label>
  <select formControlName="color">
    <option *ngFor="let item of colorSC$ | async" [value]="item?.code">{{ item?.description }}</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>

  <label>Brand:</label>
  <select formControlName="brand">
    <option *ngFor="let item of brandSC$ | async" [value]="item?.code">{{ item?.description }}</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>

  <label>Size:</label>
  <select formControlName="size">
    <option *ngFor="let item of this.sizeSC$ | async" [value]="item?.code">{{ item?.description }}</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>

  <label>Fruit:</label>
  <select formControlName="fruit">
    <option *ngFor="let item of fruitSC$ | async" [value]="item?.code">{{ item?.description }}</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>

  <button type="submit">Ok</button>
</form>
```

In your service you do not have to map them as you are doing nothing useful you are returning the same thing

```
export class CatalogueService {
  requestOptions: any;
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
    });
    this.requestOptions = {headers, observe: 'response'};
  }
  getColors() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getColors', this.requestOptions).pipe(map(res => res.body));
  }
  getBrands() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getBrands', this.requestOptions).pipe(map(res => res.body));
  }
  getSizes() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getSizes', this.requestOptions).pipe(map(res => res.body));
  }
  getFruits() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getFruits', this.requestOptions).pipe(map(res => res.body));
  }
}
```

So you can get rid of ngOnInit ngOnDestroy since you won't be needing them for this use case. Its better to hook it up at the constructor level as they can operate at constructor level itself

---